# Firebase auth/argument-error Google Authentication in angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here is my code in a method within my authentication service (Angular app)

```
let provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

return this.angularFireAuth.signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => {result.user});
```

This fails and I get Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).

I have debugged the error and the point at which it fails is in a firebase method called `_assertInstanceOf` where it checks whether the authorization provider (in this case GoogleAuthProvider) is a subclass of FederatedAuthProvider - which on examination definitely is.

```
function _assertInstanceOf(auth, object, instance) {
    const constructorInstance = instance;
    if (!(object instanceof constructorInstance)) {
        if (constructorInstance.name !== object.constructor.name) {
            _fail(auth, "argument-error" /* AuthErrorCode.ARGUMENT_ERROR */);
        }
        throw _errorWithCustomMessage(auth, "argument-error" /* AuthErrorCode.ARGUMENT_ERROR */, `Type of ${object.constructor.name} does not match expected instance.` +
            `Did you pass a reference from a different Auth SDK?`);
    }
}
```

The test:

```
if (constructorInstance.name !== object.constructor.name)
```

Evaluates to

```
"FederatedAuthProvider" !== "GoogleAuthProvider"
```

And therefore the `_fail` method is called.

Is this a bug in the Firebase code or something else?

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "firebase": "^10.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
```

Comment: Did you manage to get around this?